# How does changing the moment of inertia of an object being swung by a human affect the kinetic energy?

Tags: angular-momentum, everyday-life, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

If a human swings a baseball bat with moment of inertia $I$ at velocity $\omega$, as hard as he/she can the swing has a given kinetic energy. If you increase $I$, then the human will not be able to swing with the same $\omega$. My intuition is that there is a certain maximum momentum the human can produce which remains constant, and that I can determine kinetic energy by calculating the new $\omega$ by $\omega = L_{max}/I$ where $L_{max}$ is the maximum momentum the human can produce. Is this solution correct?

Edit: I don't want to make this about bio-mechanics. Make all the "Spherical human in a vacuum" assumptions necessary, and ignore edge cases such as extremely light or heavy bats.

Comment: $\omega$ is *angular* velocity, which is different from velocity. $L$ is *angular* momentum, which is different from momentum.

Comment: I think I've made it clear I'm working with angular velocity throughout the question

Comment: *"If you increase , then the human will not be able to swing with the same ."* Has certain implicit assumptions that are not universally, bio-mechanically correct. There are built in speed limits to the contraction of muscle cells which mean that the achievable angular speed is roughly independent of low moments of inertia. Not that the question is totally trashed as there are ranges of $I$ for which the statement is reasonable.

Comment: This question is really not about physics but rather about human biomechanics.

Comment: Please see edit. As dmckee said, there are ranges for $I$ where the question makes sense. I only care about those ranges.